# How to simplify this so that search takes less time?

Tags: linq-to-sql

```
string name = null;

foreach (var dealer in contact)
{
    if (name != null)
        break;
    if (name == null)
    {
        foreach (var emp in dealer.employees)
        {
            if (emp.id == primarySalespersonId)
            {
                if (emp.personFirstName != null)
                    name = emp.personFirstName;
                else
                    name = "No Name";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

There are same multiple tables named contact. And each contact table has multiple dealer tables. I need a method to simplify this search using LINQ or any other better way. Please Help

Comment: Could you give us more info about the entities? 
I mean the classes and maybe the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first optimisation you can do is to replace the inner loop to look for the employee by id, eg

```
string name = null;
foreach (var dealer in contact)
{
   var emp= dealer.employees.Where(e=>e.Id == primarySalespersonId).FirstOrDefault();
   if (emp!= null)
   {
       if (emp.personFirstName != null)
            name = emp.personFirstName;
       else
            name = "No Name";
   }

   if (name != null)
       break;
}
```

Going further, requires making some assumptions.

When a table has a column named 'id, then I would assume it means the column is an **unique** identity column.

If contact represents **every** dealer (as opposed to a selection of dealers) and if every employee belongs to a dealer, then you should be able to look up the id directly.

```
   var emp = employees.Where(e=>e.Id == primarySalespersonId).SingleOrDefault();
   if (emp != null)
   {
       if (emp.personFirstName != null)
            name = emp.personFirstName;
       else
            name = "No Name";
   }
```